# Android - Exchange encryption - SD card 'damaged'

Tags: exchange, encryption, htc

Mrs has a HTC One S, asked me to set up her work email on exchange.  No problem.  Got to the device admin-security policy part; a little bit surprised by requesting encryption & pin lock but what the heck hit OK.  Never used it before, never expected problems.

Upon further reading it looks like this process is supposed to take an hour, after hitting OK it went straight to the mailbox and failed to sync.  Rechecked pass & server settings, no go so removed account, administrator, cleared saved credentials and rebooted.

- First surprise, PIN lock is still enabled.
- Second surprise, "SD Card is damaged."

Did some research, my understanding security policies cannot be removed while SD card is encrypted.  Storage shows phone storage as encrypted and SD as not mounted.  Tried a few tricks like re-adding account and then then attempting to remove encryption without success.  VPN settings are nill.

This is not removable storage, so left with options in phone.

At a loss so here I am at 'phone a friend' if anybody has any idea.  Would really like to recover media from SD if at all possible.

Cheers.